# TestCafe docker- unable to run tests using runner class

Tags: docker, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have all my tests running in a docker container and it works fine. Since I have a few test files which need concurrent tests and a file which doesn't need a concurrent test that is the reason I need to create a test runner to run my tests. Here is what my test runner class looks like:

```
const createTestCafe = require('testcafe');

let testcafe = null;

createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338)
  .then((tc) => {
    testcafe = tc;
    const runner1 = testcafe.createRunner();
    const runner2 = testcafe.createRunner();

    const promise1 = runner1
      .src(['/tests/uitests/**/conctests/accounttest.js', '/tests/uitests/**/conctests/dashtest.js'])
      .browsers('chromium')
      .screenshots({ takeOnFails: true })
      .reporter(['spec', {
        name: 'html',
        output: 'resultsrunner1.html' }, {
        name: 'xunit',
        output: 'res1.xml',
      }])
      .concurrency(3)
      .run({
        skipJsErrors: true,
        quarantineMode: true,
      });

    const promise2 = runner2
      .src('/tests/uitests/**/conctests/roletest.js')
      .browsers('chromium')
      .screenshots({ takeOnFails: true })
      .reporter(['spec', {
        name: 'html',
        output: 'resultsrunner2.html' }, {
        name: 'xunit',
        output: 'res2.xml',
      }])
      .run({
        skipJsErrors: true,
        quarantineMode: true,
      });

    return Promise.all([promise1, promise2]);
  })
  .then(() => {
    testcafe.close();
    process.exit();
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    testcafe.close();
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

when I run it using the command:

```
docker run --net=host -v `pwd`:/tests -it --entrypoint node testcafe /tests/testrunner.js
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Unable to establish one or more of the specified browser connections. This can be caused by network issues or remote device failure.
at /tests/node_modules/testcafe/src/runner/browser-set.js:84:30
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at step (/tests/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:17:30)
at /tests/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:35:14
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at new F (/tests/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_export.js:36:28)
at /tests/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:14:12
at BrowserSet._waitConnectionsOpened (/tests/node_modules/testcafe/src/runner/browser-set.js:77:37)
at _waitConnectionsOpened (/tests/node_modules/testcafe/src/runner/browser-set.js:107:35)
at invokeCallback (/tests/node_modules/pinkie/index.js:60:12)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at publish (/tests/node_modules/pinkie/index.js:147:32)
at Array.publishFulfillment (/tests/node_modules/pinkie/index.js:152:2)
at Immediate.asyncFlush (/tests/node_modules/pinkie/index.js:17:19)
at runCallback (timers.js:706:11)
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:126:23)
```

I tried `firefox` and `chromium --no-sandbox` as well but nothing worked for me. In my case, I'm using the existing available browser image from the TestCafe. Please suggest as all my tests are stuck right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use a headless browser. If you need to run tests with the browser UI, perform this [step](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/master/docker/testcafe-docker.sh#L6) in your runner to initialize the in-memory display server.

Comment: tests are supposed to run in headless mode by default. The `Firefox` and `Chromium` are the headless browsers which comes along with the TestCafe image

Comment: It works on my side with the `chromium:headless` option, but I get the same error as you with the `chromium` option.

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. One more question, If I add `runner.screenshots({
    takeOnFails: true
});` then I get error `TypeError: input.replace is not a function` but if I just use `runner.screenshots()` without any arguments then it doesn't throw any error. I'm not sure what's wrong with the argument `takeOnFails: true`?

Comment: I created an issue here: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4475 . If it works for you then please let me know how?

Comment: Thank you for the provided information. We will examine your case. Please stay tuned for updates in this thread: github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4475.